# Metadata regarding PL/SQL package-level record types

Tags: oracle, reflection, plsql

Suppose you have a PL/SQL package with a `RECORD` type defined:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PACKAGE AS

    TYPE PERSON_RECORD_TYPE IS RECORD
    (
        first_name VARCHAR2(1000),
        last_name  VARCHAR2(1000)
    );

END;
```

Is there any way to obtain a list of fields contained within `TEST_PACKAGE.PERSON_RECORD_TYPE`? For example, are there any `ALL_*` views with this information?

I am not interested in *schema*-level record types, only *package*-level record types.

Comment: obtain the fields from within the same package?

Comment: @tbone: Not necessarily. I would like to obtain the fields from a different package.

Comment: "obtain them" meaning to use them how?  Can u give some pseudo code of what you are trying to accomplish in this other package?

Comment: What do you want to do with this data?  Is this to assist a developer task such as impact analysis?  Or some sort of dynamic programming exercise?

Comment: @APC: I was aiming to automatically generate some PL/SQL code based upon the fields in that record type.

Answer (score 2):

If PERSON_RECORD_TYPE is used as argument or result type of some procedure or function, you can query ALL_ARGUMENTS. The information is little bit encrypted there (the hierarchy of multilevel encapsulation of records and collections is encoded in POSITION,SEQUENCE and DATA_LEVEL columns), however it is present.

I don't think such a question points to wrong architecture. For automatic PLSQL code generation this is completely legitimate request, unfortunately with very weak PLSQL language support.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution after Oracle 18c

I think this didn't work prior to 18c (correct me if I'm wrong), but now we can query the [`ALL_PLSQL_TYPE_ATTRS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/ALL_PLSQL_TYPE_ATTRS.html) view:

```sql
SELECT type_name, attr_name, attr_type_name, length
FROM all_plsql_type_attrs
WHERE package_name = 'TEST_PACKAGE'
ORDER BY owner, package_name, type_name, attr_no;
```

To get something like this:

```
TYPE_NAME           ATTR_NAME   ATTR_TYPE_NAME  LENGTH
------------------------------------------------------
PERSON_RECORD_TYPE  FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2        1000
PERSON_RECORD_TYPE  LAST_NAME   VARCHAR2        1000
```

#### Solution prior to Oracle 18c

[jOOQ's code generator](http://www.jooq.org) internally uses the following query to reliably find all package level `PL/SQL RECORD` types:

```sql
SELECT
  "x"."TYPE_OWNER",
  "x"."TYPE_NAME",
  "x"."TYPE_SUBNAME","a".subprogram_id,
  "a"."ARGUMENT_NAME" "ATTR_NAME",
  "a"."SEQUENCE" "ATTR_NO",
  "a"."TYPE_OWNER" "ATTR_TYPE_OWNER",
  nvl2("a"."TYPE_SUBNAME", "a"."TYPE_NAME", NULL) "package_name",
  COALESCE("a"."TYPE_SUBNAME", "a"."TYPE_NAME", "a"."DATA_TYPE") "ATTR_TYPE_NAME",
  "a"."DATA_LENGTH" "LENGTH",
  "a"."DATA_PRECISION" "PRECISION",
  "a"."DATA_SCALE" "SCALE"
FROM "SYS"."ALL_ARGUMENTS" "a"
JOIN (
  SELECT
    "a"."TYPE_OWNER",
    "a"."TYPE_NAME",
    "a"."TYPE_SUBNAME",
    MIN("a"."OWNER") KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
      ORDER BY "a"."OWNER" ASC, "a"."PACKAGE_NAME" ASC, 
               "a"."SUBPROGRAM_ID" ASC, "a"."SEQUENCE" ASC) "OWNER",
    MIN("a"."PACKAGE_NAME") KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
      ORDER BY "a"."OWNER" ASC, "a"."PACKAGE_NAME" ASC, 
               "a"."SUBPROGRAM_ID" ASC, "a"."SEQUENCE" ASC) "PACKAGE_NAME",
    MIN("a"."SUBPROGRAM_ID") KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
      ORDER BY "a"."OWNER" ASC, "a"."PACKAGE_NAME" ASC, 
               "a"."SUBPROGRAM_ID" ASC, "a"."SEQUENCE" ASC) "SUBPROGRAM_ID",
    MIN("a"."SEQUENCE") KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
      ORDER BY "a"."OWNER" ASC, "a"."PACKAGE_NAME" ASC, 
               "a"."SUBPROGRAM_ID" ASC, "a"."SEQUENCE" ASC) "SEQUENCE",
    MIN("next_sibling") KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
      ORDER BY "a"."OWNER" ASC, "a"."PACKAGE_NAME" ASC, 
               "a"."SUBPROGRAM_ID" ASC, "a"."SEQUENCE" ASC) "next_sibling",
    MIN("a"."DATA_LEVEL") KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
      ORDER BY "a"."OWNER" ASC, "a"."PACKAGE_NAME" ASC, 
               "a"."SUBPROGRAM_ID" ASC, "a"."SEQUENCE" ASC) "DATA_LEVEL"
  FROM (
    SELECT
      lead("a"."SEQUENCE", 1, 99999999) OVER (
        PARTITION BY "a"."OWNER", "a"."PACKAGE_NAME", 
                     "a"."SUBPROGRAM_ID", "a"."DATA_LEVEL"
        ORDER BY "a"."SEQUENCE" ASC
      ) "next_sibling",
      "a"."TYPE_OWNER",
      "a"."TYPE_NAME",
      "a"."TYPE_SUBNAME",
      "a"."OWNER",
      "a"."PACKAGE_NAME",
      "a"."SUBPROGRAM_ID",
      "a"."SEQUENCE",
      "a"."DATA_LEVEL",
      "a"."DATA_TYPE"
    FROM "SYS"."ALL_ARGUMENTS" "a"
    WHERE "a"."OWNER" IN ('TEST')     -- Possibly replace schema here
    ) "a"
  WHERE ("a"."TYPE_OWNER" IN ('TEST') -- Possibly replace schema here
  AND "a"."OWNER"         IN ('TEST') -- Possibly replace schema here
  AND "a"."DATA_TYPE"      = 'PL/SQL RECORD')
  GROUP BY
    "a"."TYPE_OWNER",
    "a"."TYPE_NAME",
    "a"."TYPE_SUBNAME"
  ) "x"
ON (("a"."OWNER", "a"."PACKAGE_NAME", "a"."SUBPROGRAM_ID")
 = (("x"."OWNER", "x"."PACKAGE_NAME", "x"."SUBPROGRAM_ID"))
AND "a"."SEQUENCE" BETWEEN "x"."SEQUENCE" AND "next_sibling"
AND "a"."DATA_LEVEL" = ("x"."DATA_LEVEL" + 1))
ORDER BY
  "x"."TYPE_OWNER" ASC,
  "x"."TYPE_NAME" ASC,
  "x"."TYPE_SUBNAME" ASC,
  "a"."SEQUENCE" ASC
```

In your case, the result will be something like:

```
TYPE_NAME     TYPE_SUBNAME        ATTR_NAME   ATTR_TYPE_NAME   LENGTH
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST_PACKAGE  PERSON_RECORD_TYPE  FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2         1000
TEST_PACKAGE  PERSON_RECORD_TYPE  LAST_NAME   VARCHAR2         1000
```

Current limitations:

- The query will find only those types that are referenced by at least one other type and/or procedure somewhere. This is a limitation inherited from the `ALL_ARGUMENTS` dictionary view in the query.
- `%ROWTYPE` types are not returned correctly because the row type is not referenced from the `TYPE_NAME` / `TYPE_SUBNAME` columns.

More information here:
https://blog.jooq.org/2016/11/08/use-jooq-to-read-write-oracle-plsql-record-types

Comment: ALL_PLSQL_TYPE_ATTRS is actually available as far back as  12.1.0.2

Comment: In fact it is available in 12.1.0.1 according to the [changelog](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-509A6343-5882-4260-BAD0-DC6B2BDC8301.htm#GUID-ABA782DF-DBEA-4252-BF01-E52CE2210875).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some similar questions about retrieving information from package code.

[Find package global variables from data dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915045/find-package-global-variables-from-data-dictionary)

[Get Package Methods and Parameters from Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582325/get-package-methods-and-parameters-from-oracle)

I see this as a similar problem like first one. You cannot acces those fields via a view. There is the parse source text solution, which is ugly, or you may need an workaround to this.

Anyway, I think it is something wrong in your architecture if you need this.

Comment: wouldn't this would be better off as a comment than an answer?