# How can I get list of defined types within a package in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Metadata regarding PL/SQL package-level record types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804285/metadata-regarding-pl-sql-package-level-record-types)

I have defined some custom types in some packages in an Oracle database. I need a SQL query to get the list of all defined types in a specific package from that Oracle database. Furthermore, By knowing the Object ID of a type, I want to get all the attributes of that type from the Oracle database. I need to know the full specification of each type including its name, its attributes and also the full specification of each attribute including name, type, position and etc.

Comment: I think there is no such query that can get you that, unless you write a special query on `user_source` with type=`PACKAGE BODY` and do some sort of scan for types.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from user_types;
select * from user_type_attrs;
select * from user_type_methods;
select * from user_procedures;
select * from user_source;
```

Comment: Will this find the definition of types, etc, **defined in packages**?